# FLUME EXCEPTION

Tags: twitter, flume

I am trying to configure flume and am following [this link](https://www.eduonix.com/blog/bigdata-and-hadoop/flume-installation-and-streaming-twitter-data-using-flume/).  The following command works for me:

```
flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent -c conf -f /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.7.0-bin/conf/flume.conf
```

The result I got with error is,

```
17/01/31 12:04:08 INFO source.DefaultSourceFactory: Creating instance of source Twitter, type com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource  
17/01/31 12:04:08 ERROR node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Failed to load configuration data.
Exception follows. org.apache.flume.FlumeException:
Unable to load source type:
 com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource, class:
 com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource.
```

(This is part of the result, I just copied the error part of it)

Can anyone help to solve this error please? I need to fix it to go on step 24 which is the last step.

Comment: If you are still with the project, can you add the whole error? And it will be interesting as well the flume.conf content

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, i solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Please find CDH 5.12 Flume Twitter Setup:

**1.** Here is file */usr/lib/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf*:

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type= com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = Hadoop,BigData  
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/flume/tweets/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

**2.** Rename the below *flume-env.sh.template* file as *flume-env.sh*

~]$ sudo cp /usr/lib/flume-ng/conf/flume-env.sh.template /usr/lib/flume-ng/conf/flume-env.sh

**3.** Set **JAVA_HOME** and **FLUME_CLASSPATH** in *flume-env.sh* file as:

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera

FLUME_CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

**4.** If you don't find *"/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"* on your system then download the **apache-flume-1.6.0-bin** from google and copy **lib** folder of this to current **lib** folder.

*Link:* https://www.apache.org/dist/flume/1.6.0/apache-flume-1.6.0-bin.tar.gz

**4.1.** Rename old lib folder

**4.2.** Download this above link to your cloudera desktop and do the following:

~]$ sudo  mv /usr/lib/flume-ng/lib /usr/lib/flume-ng/lib_cloudera

~]$ sudo  mv /home/cloudera/Desktop/apache-flume-1.6.0-bin/lib /usr/lib/flume-ng/lib

**5.** Now run Flume Agent Command:

~]$ flume-ng agent --conf-file /usr/lib/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf --name TwitterAgent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -n TwitterAgent

This should run successfully.
All the Best.